# zlib data not decompressing

Tags: ios, nsdata, zlib

I am making a request to my server which is passing back a bunch of Data that contains header information which is uncompressed then the data which has been requested which should be compressed using zlib.

so the whole load of data looks something like

> (header (uncompressed) / data (compressed) / end)

Prior to this the data was never compressed, so this is how I access the information in there

```
cstring = (char *) malloc(sizeWithLocalOrdering + 1);
            strncpy(cstring, bytes, sizeWithLocalOrdering);
            cstring[sizeWithLocalOrdering] = '\0';
            NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            methodResponseData =[resultString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

sizeWithLocalOrdering is how big the data portion is so i can read it correctly from all the data I am receiving from the server.

But now that I am reciving Zlib data.. I would like to know how I get the data portion out of the stuff Im being sent without breaking zlib compression... because currently when I feed MethodResponseData into my decompression method showen below

```
- (NSData*) dataByDecompressingData:(NSData*)data{
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
    Byte* bytes = (Byte*)[data bytes];
    NSInteger len = [data length];
    NSMutableData *decompressedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:COMPRESSION_BLOCK];
    Byte* decompressedBytes = (Byte*) malloc(COMPRESSION_BLOCK);

    z_stream stream;
    int err;
    stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
    stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
    stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;

    stream.next_in = bytes;
//  err = inflateInit(&stream);
    err = inflateInit2(&stream, -MAX_WBITS);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateInit");

    while (true) {
        stream.avail_in = len - stream.total_in;
        stream.next_out = decompressedBytes;
        stream.avail_out = COMPRESSION_BLOCK;
        err = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        [decompressedData appendBytes:decompressedBytes length:(stream.total_out-[decompressedData length])];
        if(err == Z_STREAM_END)
            break;
        CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflate");
    }

    err = inflateEnd(&stream);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateEnd");

    free(decompressedBytes);
    return decompressedData;
}
```

its saying Data is .. and I am defiantly sending methodReasponse across that is defiantly NSData... so the only reason I can put it down to being like this is because of my receiver method pulling the data from the response like I am.

So two things, Do you think this is the reason for the ? and secondly how do you think I can fix the data so it is actually NSData and the compression is still there so I can decompress with my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to change the way I get the Bytes from the Data I recive to this

```
myCompressedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeWithLocalOrdering];
```

this means there is no stuffing around with the compression formatting unlike before, then I found another issue with this line of code

```
err = inflateInit2(&stream, -MAX_WBITS);
```

so I changed it back to the original

```
err = inflateInit(&stream);
```

and it all worked out correctly.